# Как разделить leading на несколько разных частей со своей разметкой?

Tags: joomla, joomla3

Всем **привет**!

Есть код (файл blog.php), который отвечает за вывод вводных текста, изображения и т. д. статьи во всю ширину:

```
<?php if (!empty($this->lead_items)) : ?>
    <div class="items-leading clearfix">
        <?php foreach ($this->lead_items as &$item) : ?>
            <div class="leading-<?php echo $leadingcount; ?><?php echo $item->state == 0 ? ' system-unpublished' : null; ?>" itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BlogPosting">
                <?php
                    $this->item = &$item;
                    echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php $leadingcount++; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif;
```

Я бы хотел разделить его на несколько частей чтобы сделать что-то типа этого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
т. е. с одной стороны - слайдер (уже сделано (без модулей)), отображающий (например 3-и вводных статьи), а с другой - статические 3(4,5...)-и вводных статьи... Т. е., я, в админке, в "Редактирование пункта меню" --> "Параметры макета Блога" --> "Во всю ширину", указываю (например) цифру 6-ть в надежде того, что 3-и вводных статьи будут отображаться в слайдере, а остальные (следующие по дате публикации) 3-и вводных статьи - справа от слайдера, а уже ниже (назовем это "под слайдером"), будут отображаться остальные (следйющие по дате публикации) вводные статьи... Ну т. е. те вводные статьи, за которые отвечает код:

```
<?php if (!empty($this->intro_items)) : ?>
        <?php foreach ($this->intro_items as $key => &$item) : ?>
            <?php $rowcount = ((int) $key % (int) $this->columns) + 1; ?>
            <?php if ($rowcount === 1) : ?>
                <?php $row = $counter / $this->columns; ?>
                <div class="items-row cols-<?php echo (int) $this->columns; ?> <?php echo 'row-' . $row; ?> row-fluid clearfix">
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="span<?php echo round(12 / $this->columns); ?>">
                <div class="item column-<?php echo $rowcount; ?><?php echo $item->state == 0 ? ' system-unpublished' : null; ?>" itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BlogPosting">
                    <?php
                        $this->item = &$item;
                        echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
                    ?>
                </div>

                <?php $counter++; ?>
            </div>

            <?php if (($rowcount == $this->columns) or ($counter == $introcount)) : ?>
                </div>

            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif;
```

Надеюсь нормально объяснил чего хочу...

Подскажите плз, как это сделать? Понимаю что нужно как-то прописать условие в foreach... но как это сделать - не пойму...

Заранее **благодарю за ответы**!

**P**. **S**.

  Использование модулей - не предлагать!

Answer (score 1):

Как всегда все оказалось как нельзя просто!

В приведенном выше коде (последний код в первом посту) файла blog.php, в

```
<?php
$this->item = &$item;
echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
?>
```

нежно вставить перед циклом вот эту строку:

```
$myarr = array_slice($this->intro_items, 3);
```

и в цикле foreach заменить

```
$this->intro_items
```

на

```
$myarr
```

чтобы получилось вот так:

```
<?php 
$myarr = array_slice($this->intro_items, 3);
foreach ($myarr_items as $key => &$item) :
?>
```

тогда, вводные статьи будут выводиться не с первой (если первая статья - последняя опубликованная), а с 3-й вводной статьи. Если вместо тройки поставить (например) 4-е, то будет отображены статьи, начиная с 4-й вводной статьи... Ну, думаю понятно... Если не понятно - попробуйте скопировать код и поэксперементировать...

Ну и там, где нужно вывести те вводные статьи, которые мы "пропустили" выше, пишем следующий код:

```
<?php if (!empty($this->intro_items)) :
$myarr = array_slice($this->intro_items, 0, 3);
foreach ($myarr as $key => &$item) :
$this->item = &$item;
echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
endforeach;
endif; ?>
```

после чего, будут отображены недостающие вводные статьи.

Для того, чтобы изменить разметку этих статей, в

```
echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
```

заменяем item на какой-нибудь свой файл, предварительно его создав в `templates/my_template/html/com_content/category`

*например*: blog_slider.php. Тогда вместо ***item***, пишем ***slider***.